# HTTR GET next_offset

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

Spinning my wheels on this API Get repsonse. I can get the first 20 observations but cannot figure out how to iterate through the "Next_Offset" which is 20.

content of the GET response returns 2 lists:

1. next offset
2. list of 20 lists

I'm trying to paginate through each 20 until there is no data left and during each iteration bind the data into a final list.

```
authHeader <- add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer",apiKey))

resp <- GET(
  paste0(connectServer, apiPrefix),
  authHeader)

payload <- content(resp)

### Create empty list to bind during pagination
payload_list <- list()


while(length(payload$next_offset) > 0) {
  
  newdata <- payload$records
  
  cbind(payload_list,newdata )
  
  nextPage <- payload$records + 1
  
  resp <- GET(
    paste0(connectServer, apiPrefix, "&page_number=", nextPage),
    authHeader
  )
  payload <- content(resp)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using

```
while(length(payload$next_offset) > 0) {
  
  newdata <- payload$records
  
  cbind(payload_list,newdata )
  
  nextPage <- payload$new_offset
  
  resp <- GET(
    paste0(connectServer, apiPrefix, "?offset=", nextPage),
    authHeader
  )
  payload <- content(resp)
}
```